# Can I respond "hello" to someone who greets me in the middle of davening if it will ruin my Kavanah by not responding?

Tags: tefilla, speech-talking

Example: I'm in the middle of saying פסוקי דזמרה and one of my dad's friends comes up to me and says "hello...". Do I have to ignore him or may I respond "hi".

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13684/759

Comment: You will likely find that feeling unsure afterwards if you really could say hello will ruin your kavana as much as not saying hello

Comment: Your title says "davening" and the question body says "Example: I'm in the middle of saying פסוקי דזמרה". aBochur's answer addressed just your example. If you meant to ask about other parts of davening, as well, the answer is incomplete, as there are areas where you may answer and others where you may not. Please edit your question so it is clear as to what you wish to know.

Answer (score 3):

Shulchan Aruch ([OC 51:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.51.5?with=all&lang=bi)) when discussing the laws of Pesukei Dezimra,  says as follows:

> בין המזמורים האלו שואל מפני הכבוד ומשיב שלום לכל אדם ובאמצע המזמור שואל מפני הירא' ומשיב מפני הכבוד:
>
> In between these psalms one may ask [of another's welfare] out of respect [for that person] and may reply greetings to any person. And in the middle of the psalm he may ask [of another's welfare] out of fear and he may reply out of respect.

In short, even if it's not going to ruin your concentration by not replying, you are still allowed to do so in between paragraphs.

Nevertheless, the Mishna Berura in [66:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.66.2?with=all&lang=bi) says that if the person will not be upset that you didn't answer him, you may not answer the greeting.

Comment: See also [Berakhot 13a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=13&format=pdf)