# Waiting for the host to recite Hamotzi to have me in mind

Tags: halacha, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, meal-seudah, bread

When washing for bread and waiting for the host to recite *Hamotzi* to have me in mind, after how long would my washing and hearing the *brocha* become a *hefsek*?

Comment: On the problem (or lack thereof) and parameter of hefsek after netillat yadayim: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84434/8775

Answer (score 1):

Yalqut Yosef - Qizur Shulhan `Arukh (Orah Hayim 166:2) [states](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_12.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A7%D7%A1%D7%95B-B%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%94B%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9FB%D7%91%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%94B%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%91) (my translation):

> נכון להזהר היכא דאפשר שלא לשהות שיעור כדי הילוך כ''ב אמה בין הנטילה לברכת המוציא. וראוי להחמיר היכא דאפשר גם בשיעור כדי הליכת כ''ב אמה בפסיעות גסות, ולא רק בשיעור של הליכה עקב בצד גודל. אולם כשבני הבית רבים, מותר להמתין להם בסעודות שבת עד שהכל יטלו ידיהם, אף שעובר זמן בין הנטילה לברכת המוציא יותר מהשיעור הנ''ל. ומכל מקום יש לזרזם ליטול ידיהם בלא שום עיכוב.
>
> It is correct to take care, when possible, not to wait the amount of time it takes to walk 22 *amot* between performing *Nettilat Yadayim* and reciting the blessing of *Hamozi*. And it is also proper to be stringent, when possible, [to arrive at this amount of time] with regard to large strides and not only those of walking ankle to toe.
>
> However, when many people eat together, it is permissible to wait for them for Shabbat meals even if the aforementioned time passes between *Nettilat Yadayim* and *Hamozi*. Nevertheless, one should encourage them not to delay.